# Edit NSMutable array at index

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray

I would like to read in an Array I have stored in a PLIST, modify an element, and store it back to the PLIST.

My simple code is as follows:

```
NSArray *mathScoreArray;
NSNumber *score1 = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:score];
NSMutableArray *scoreArray1 = [[NSArray arrayWithArray:mathScoreArray] init];
[scoreArray1 replaceObjectAtIndex:4 withObject:score1];
[dictionary setObject:scoreArray1 forKey :@"mathScoreArray"];
[dictionary writeToFile:finalPath atomically:YES];
```

I'm getting errors for the 'replaceObjectAtIndex' for modifying the array. 
How can I do this??

Just for reference, my plist looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>mathQues</key>
    <integer>1</integer>
    <key>mathScore</key>
    <integer>0</integer>
    <key>mathScoreArray</key>
    <array>
        <integer>10</integer>
        <integer>20</integer>
        <integer>30</integer>
        <integer>40</integer>
        <integer>50</integer>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Extending the problem, eventually I would like to shift the array one place to right and store a new incoming value on top [just like a stack].

Thanks for pointers.
user

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this line:

```
    NSMutableArray *scoreArray1 = [[NSArray arrayWithArray:mathScoreArray] init];
// you need NSMutableArray, not NSArray ^
//                           you already got an array, no need to initialize ^
```

to:

```
    NSMutableArray *scoreArray1 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:mathScoreArray];
```

Also, in your code there is no sign of how did you read the `NSArray` to begin with.

Comment: Hi Binyamin, thanks for your help. I changed my code quite a lot after posting the question. Currently, the PLIST has 3 elements, two Numbers and one Array with 5 elements. All I would like is to be able to read the existing array of scores from the PLIST, and push the new score on  top of this score array, and write it back into the PLIST.   In this context, I'm not sure if the NSMutableArray for mathScoreArray(from PLIST) is a correct choice, is it?? Thanks, user